# Remove trailing newline after a git commit

Tags: git

I just committed and pushed a change that accidentally added a new line to the end of every file in my repo. Now that my diff is really big, is there anyway I can remove these newlines?

Comment: The answers given are correct. I want to add that you can write a script which remove trailing newline characters at the end of your file and use the output of `git diff --name-only HEAD^` (assuming you have the commit in question checked out) to get the names of all files you changed in the commit.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only change, you can `git reset --hard HEAD^` to move your `HEAD` to the previous commit and then `git push --force` assuming no one else has pulled yet.

If your change is more than just the newlines, you'll have to `reset`, fix up the commit and then `push --force` again assuming that no one else has pulled in between.

Answer (score 0):

here try this by using this you can undo your last commit

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

then make the changes to your files and commit again.

here refer this for more: 
[How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit)

Comment: This will be really dangerous for his git history, cause he already pushed the commit, so coming back will be a damage.

Answer (score 0):

## The right **and SAFE** way

is to do it is to use `git-revert`, cause you already pushed the commit to the repository

### The wrong and DANGEROUS way

is instead performing a simple `git-reset`, like

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

or

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

because they will step back to the previous commit, but when you will commit again you will diverge and will be rewriting you *git history*; and that should be avoided as much as possible.

Note that there is (almost) always something wrong and smelling when you find yourself using the **--force** option, or when you try to diverge (take another path and forget the previous. ***Git** doesn't like to forget things*)) from pushed commits
(in fact the commits will remain orphans and you will rewrite the history creating problems to other repository users).

## To do it use

```
git revert HEAD
```

This is made exactly for cases like that, and will make a new commit that will put all the files back to the previous commit, undoing the ending line.
You need to make a new commit if you want to preserve the integrity of your repository.